# i am converting an image to a byte array but fail to get an image from same byte array

Tags: ios, swift2

I have two image views one image view is to show image pick from gallary and the the second image view is to show the image which is converted from `NSData` to `[UINT8]` and from `[UINT8]` to `UIImage`

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]){

    imagePickerController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    importImage.image=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

    let imageData:NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(importImage.image!,1)!

    let imageata=convertionofImageToByteArray(imageData)


   let cadenaImagen=imageata as NSArray



   convertedImage.image = convierteImagen(cadenaImagen)

}
```

the below method to convert an image to byte array

```
func convertionofImageToByteArray(imageData:NSData)->NSMutableArray{

    let count = imageData.length / sizeof(UInt8)

    // create array of appropriate length:
    var bytes = [UInt8](count: count, repeatedValue: 0)

    // copy bytes into array
    imageData.getBytes(&bytes, length:count * sizeof(UInt8))

    let byteArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    for i in 0..<count{
        byteArray.addObject(NSNumber(unsignedChar: bytes[i]))
    }

    return byteArray

}
```

the below method to convert byte array to image

```
func convierteImagen(cadenaImagen: NSArray) -> UIImage? {

    var bytes = [UInt8]()
    for i in 0..<cadenaImagen.count {
        if let signedByte = Int8(String(cadenaImagen[i])) {
            bytes.append(UInt8(bitPattern: signedByte))
        } else {
            // Do something with this error condition
        }
    }
    let datos: NSData = NSData(bytes: bytes, length: bytes.count)
    return UIImage(data: datos) // Note it's optional. Don't force unwrap!!!
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? NSData _is_ a byte array. What is the point of trying to transform it to and from an NSArray?

Comment: actually i am sending that byte array to server and again that byte array receive  and convert it as image data

Comment: Why are you using a signed byte!!??

Comment: WTF??? You are filling an array with NSNumber objects! You don't have a byte array, you have an array with gazillions of full blown NSObjects! On a 64 bit device, this is horrible. On a 32 bit device, this will go kaboom! And carefully, carefully read matt's comment. What you are doing is absolutely hilarious. NSData IS A BYTE ARRAY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is beyond me why you would think that typecasting unsigned byte to a signed byte would work. You actually even have a comment to handle the error there and it hits that error every time the overflow occurs (result is nil).

So try this:

```
func convierteImagen(cadenaImagen: NSArray) -> UIImage? {

        var bytes = [UInt8]()
        for i in 0..<cadenaImagen.count {
            if let  signed = UInt8(String(cadenaImagen[i])) {
                bytes.append(signed)
            } else {
                // Do something with this error condition
            }
        }
        let datos: NSData = NSData(bytes: bytes, length: bytes.count)
        return UIImage(data: datos) // Note it's optional. Don't force unwrap!!!
    }
```

The statement `if let signedByte = Int8(String(cadenaImagen[i])) {` will fail for any value in `bytes` where value is larger then `127`.

Comment: I copied your methods into my project and used a static image to try it out and it worked with this fix. Try doing the same and if it works for a static image then the issue is elsewhere. But using a signed byte was definitely an issue.